# Active Record: User_id not being assigned in nested relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have nested relationships and built them according to the [Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association). 
A `User` has many `Collections` that have many `Sections` each containing many `Links`. When creating a new `Link` though, the `user_id` is not being assigned but is always `nil`. The `section_id` and `collection_id` are being set correctly.

### Controller

```
class Api::V1::LinksController < Api::V1::BaseController
  acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User, only: [:create]

  def create
    @link = Link.new(link_params)
    @link.user_id = current_user
    authorize @link
    if @link.save
      render :show, status: :created
    else
      render_error
    end
  end

  private

  def link_params
    params.require(:resource).permit(:title, :description, :category, :image, :type, :url, :collection_id, :user_id, :section_id)
  end

  def render_error
    render json: { errors: @resource.errors.full_messages },
      status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

### Models

**User**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  acts_as_token_authenticatable
  has_many :collections, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :sections, through: :collections, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :links, through: :sections, dependent: :destroy

  mount_uploader :image, PhotoUploader
end
```

**Collection**

```
class Collection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :sections, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :links, through: :sections, dependent: :destroy

  mount_uploader :image, PhotoUploader
end
```

**Section**

```
class Section < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :collection
  has_many :links, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**Link**

```
class Link < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :section
end
```

Is this the correct way to set up the relationships and can someone help me understand what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do

```
@link.user_id = current_user
```

You could (instead) do...

```
@link.user_id = current_user.id
```

Or more elegantly...

```
@link.user = current_user
```

Which assumes you will define the relationship in the model

```
class Link < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :section
  belongs_to :user
end
```

But as Andrew Schwartz points out in the comments, it may have been a design mistake to add the field `user_id` to the `links` table. You have in the `User` model `has_many :links, through: :sections, dependent: :destroy` which does not use any user_id field in the link record. It uses the `user_id` field in the `collections` table

Just adding `user_id` to the `links` table will NOT mean that link will be returned when you do `my_user.links` ... it won't be.

Since you're passing a `section_id` in the `link_params` that is enough to create the link to the user, so just write a migration to remove the `user_id` field.  If you want to be able to see the associated user from the link, do...

```
class Link < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :section
  has_one :collection, through: :section
  has_one :user, through: :collection
end
```

and that will let you do `my_link.user` to retrieve the link's user.

Comment: Great, thank you! `@link.user_id = current_user.id` works. The second solution `@link.user = current_user` doesn't work however and returns error `"undefined method user=' for #<Link:...`

Comment: The latter doesn't work because you haven't defined the `user` association on `Link`. You can do so by setting up the necessary `has_many :through` associations: `Section.has_one :user, through: :coillection`, and `Link.has_one :user, through: :section`. But this is an *independent* source of information from `Link#user_id`, so I wouldn't use both methods. As it is `link.user_id` could possibly get out of sync with `link.section.collection.user_id`, which is one reason you might prefer the through associations to the column.

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz good points well made.  I'll edit my answer but f you want to post an answer I'd definitely upvote it.